# A regular expression for one only character

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a big file with lines like the following (tab separated):

```
220995146   A   G   1/1:8:0:0:8:301:-5,-2.40824,0   pass
221020849   G   GGAGAGGCA   1/1:8:0:0:8:229:-5,-2.40824,0   pass
```

I'm trying to write a coitional state that will allows me to keep only the lines that in the second and the third columns will have only one character.
For example, the second line doesn't pass.
The regex that I'm using is:

```
if (($ref =~ m/\w{1}/) && ($allele =~ m/\w{1}/)) {
            print "$mline\n";
    }
```

But unfortunately doesn't work.
Any suggestions?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Split by `\s+` then check for length of 2nd and 3rd element in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not needed here, you can use the [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) function:

```
if (length($ref) == 1 && length($allele) == 1) {
    print $mline,"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `$allele` contains the third column. In your code, `$allele =~ m/\w{1}/`, you check whether it *contains* one word character. Instead, you want to match the whole thing. You can do this with the begin `^` and `$` end matchers:

```
$allele =~ m/^\w{1}$/
```

Or just

```
$allele =~ /^\w$/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for pure regex solution then use:

```
$re = m/^[^\t]+\t+\w\t+\w\t+.*$/ ;
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU4lG6/3)

This will match lines where 2nd and 3rd columns have single word character by using `\w` after 1 or more tabs at 2nd and 3rd position.